# Upper bound of $\left|\sum_{n,k} c_{n,k}\, \alpha_k\right|^2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

We have a double finite series, such that:
$$\sum_{n,k} |c_{n,k}|^2=1$$
What can we conclude about upper bound of $\left|\sum_{n,k} c_{n,k}\, \alpha_k\right|^2$ for $|\alpha_k|<M$? I have tried to apply Hölder inequality:
$$\left|\sum_{n,k} c_{n,k}\, \alpha_k\right|^2\leq \sum_{n,k} |c_{n,k}|^2 \sum_{n,k} |\alpha_{k}|^2= \sum_{n,k} |\alpha_{k}|^2$$
but the latter has no dependence by index $n$, and if $n=1,2,\dots,N$: $\sum_{n,k} |\alpha_{k}|^2=N\sum_{k} |\alpha_{k}|^2$. Hence, if $N$ is "big" the bound
$$\left|\sum_{n,k} c_{n,k}\, \alpha_k\right|^2\leq  N \sum_{k} |\alpha_{k}|^2$$
is not so good. Can we do better?

Comment: The quantity $\sum_{n,k} c_{n,k}\, \alpha_k$ may be infinite in your setting: take $c_{n,k}=K(nk)^{-1}$ ($K$ in order to have the sum of squares equal to $1$) and $a_k=1$.